# Behavior of STL remove() function - only rearrange container elements?

Tags: c++, stl

I've read here on StackOveflow and other sources that the behavior of the remove function is simply re-ordering the original container so that the elements that are TO BE REMOVED are moved to the end of the container and ARE NOT deleted.  They remain part of the container and the remove() function simply returns an iterator that delimits the end of the range of elements to keep.

So if you never actually trim off the portion of the container that has the values that have been 'removed', they should still be present.

But when I run the code below there are no trailing spaces after the alphanumeric characters that were not 'removed'.

```
int main()
{
    std::string test "this is a test string with a bunch of spaces to remove";
    remove(test.begin(), test.end(), ' ');
    std::cout << test << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What is going on here? Seeing as I never call test.erase() shouldn't I have a bunch of trailing spaces on my string? Is it guaranteed that the 'removed' items will still be present after calling remove()?

PS-I'm not looking for suggestions on how to best remove spaces from a string, the above is simply an illustrative example of the remove() behavior that is confusing me.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind: although algorithms usually act on any iterator range, the algorithms that move the elements around (`partition`, `remove`, ...) should not be used on sorted/indexed containers.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the above? When you say indexed containers do you mean indexable?  Containers that support [] operator? 

As far as I understand, if your container is sorted before hand, and you run remove() on it, the elements that are not removed, i.e. the ones shifted to the front of the container, will retain their ordering.

Ex:  
Source string "qwertyasdf"

sort ascending gives "adefqrstwy"

erase/remove idiom with vowel finding predicate leaves 'dfqrstw', alphabetical order retained.

Am I misundertanding what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's left at the end of your container after a call to `remove` is not necessarily the elements that were removed. It's just junk. Most likely it's "whatever was in those positions before the call to remove", but you can't rely on that either. Much like an uninitialized variable, it could be anything.

For example, the string:

```
"Hi I am Bob!\0"
```

after a call to `remove` to get rid of spaces *probably* looks like this

```
"HiIamBob!\0b!\0"
```

You won't see that on a `cout`, though, because it will stop printing once it hits the '\0'.

Comment: Ok, that's kinda what I suspected. 

The documentation that I've been looking at (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) seems pretty confident that they are left in place and are accessible.

Thought maybe this was one of those cases of undefined behavior that can be implementation specific.

Comment: You may be right on that, actually. I thought it was implementation specific, but that documentation seems to contradict me (although cplusplus.com is not always the most accurate resource). Either way, the contents of the container after the new `end` are definitely *not* the removed elements.

Comment: Just checked out my copy of the C++ standard, it the section on `std::remove` does *not* seem to require anything specific about the elements in the container after the new end.

Comment: Yeah, I think I've misunderstood what it's doing.  It's not actually moving things around so much as duplicating things forward which can overwrite some of the stuff that should be 'removed'.

What I was picturing in my head is more like the behavior of partition() or stable_partition().

Answer (score 0):

You might be willing to get [Boost.String](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/string_algo.html).

It's a collection of algorithms to act on strings.

```
boost::erase_all(test, " ");
```